# Subtracting binary numbers using two's complement

Tags: computer-science

> Assume 151 and 214 are signed 8-bit decimal integers stored in two’s complement format. Calculate 151 - 214 using saturating arithmetic. The result should be written in decimal. Show your work.

Is this right? I am new to this:

decimal   |    binary    | twos complement
   151       |   10010111   |     01101001
   214       |   11010110   |     00101010

subtract                       00111111   -> 63

Why do I get positive 63?

Comment: You can't store 214 in 8 bit signed format. It can be an 8 bit integer stored in signed 16 bit format, or it can be an 8 bit twos complement representation of a negative 7 bit number, or it can be an overflow error. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

"Two's complement format" is the normal binary representation of signed integers.  It doesn't mean that you have to perform the two's complement *operation*.

That said, this question is hard to parse.  "Assume that 151 is an 8-bit signed integer" is silly, since it's too big to be an 8-bit signed integer.  This *probably* means that you're supposed to re-interpret the (unsigned) binary representations of 151 and 214 as 8-bit signed representations, and then subtract the numbers that result:

When the representations of 151 and 214 are interpreted as signed, the bits in the 128 place become -128 instead.  The difference is 256, so 151 becomes 151-256 = -105, and 214 becomes -42.

If we calculate -105 - (-42), we get -63.  That is the same as 151-214, which is maybe the point of this question.

This is small enough not to saturate, so it doesn't matter in this case that we're using saturating arithmetic.

Normally I wouldn't answer a homework question like this, but I feel sorry that the question you have to answer is so badly written.  You should probably delete the question instead of accepting this answer.

Comment: Why is it too big to be an 8-bit signed integer?

Comment: 8-bit signed integers range from -128 to 127